# Find specific field in an array of embedded documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find specific element of array in my MongoDB document, but with all my tries query returns all array. How can I get the right object?

My collection's document looks like:

```js
{
  "Achievements": [
    {
      "AchievementID": 1,
      "AchievementEventID": 0
    },
    {
      "AchievementID": 2,
      "AchievementEventID": 1
    }
  ],
  "Buildings": [
    {
      "BuildingID": 1,
      "BuildingType": "type1"
    },
    {
      "BuildingID": 2,
      "BuildingType": "type1"
    },
  ]
}
```

I tried to get only one element of my `Achievements` array:

```
db.data.find({'Achievements.AchievementEventID': 0})
```

I expected to get only element with `AchievementEventID` equal to 0:

```
{
  "AchievementID": 1,
  "AchievementEventID": 0
}
```

But I got whole `Achievements` array.
How I could get only specific element?

[image: I just tried queries but all of these works incorrect]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Aggregation query** like in the following example. The sample `achive` collection has 3 documents:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "Achievements" : [
                {
                        "AchievementID" : 1,
                        "AchievementEventID" : 0
                },
                {
                        "AchievementID" : 2,
                        "AchievementEventID" : 1
                }
        ],
        "Buildings" : [
                {
                        "BuildingID" : 1,
                        "BuildingType" : "type1"
                },
                {
                        "BuildingID" : 2,
                        "BuildingType" : "type1"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "Achievements" : [
                {
                        "AchievementID" : 2,
                        "AchievementEventID" : 2
                }
        ],
        "Buildings" : [
                {
                        "BuildingID" : 2,
                        "BuildingType" : "type2"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 3,
        "Achievements" : [
                {
                        "AchievementID" : 31,
                        "AchievementEventID" : 1
                }
        ],
        "Buildings" : [
                {
                        "BuildingID" : 3,
                        "BuildingType" : "type3"
                }
        ]
}
```

**The Query:**

```
db.achive.aggregate( [
    { $project: { Buildings: 0} },
    { $unwind: "$Achievements" },
    { $match: { "Achievements.AchievementEventID": { $eq: 1 } } }
])
=>
{ "_id" : 1, "Achievements" : { "AchievementID" : 2, "AchievementEventID" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : 3, "Achievements" : { "AchievementID" : 31, "AchievementEventID" : 1 } }
```

I added the `_id` field to identify the documents selected.

**Updated Query:**

```
db.achive.aggregate( [
{ $unwind: "$Achievements" },
{ $match: { "Achievements.AchievementEventID": { $eq: 1 } } },
{ $project: { AchievementID:  "$Achievements.AchievementID", _id: 0} },
])
=>
{ "AchievementID" : 2 }
{ "AchievementID" : 31 }
```

Comment: Yep! It works well for me but what if I want to get only one field? Eg I want to get only AchievementID where AchievementEventID equal 1.

Comment: You can use projection ($project). You can specify which fields to get in the result. You can add one more $project stage after the final $match.

Comment: I am updating the answer with the projection to get just the AchievementID field.

Comment: Yeah, this exactly what I wanted! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use $elemMatch for that

```
db.data.find(
   { 'Achievements.AchievementEventID': 0},{Buildings:0, Achievements: {$elemMatch: {AchievementEventID: 0}}}
)
```

If the above solution doesn't for you then try the below one:

```
db.data.find({"Achievements.AchievementEventID": 0}, {Buildings: 0, 'Achievements.$': 1});
```

Comment: Sorry, my earlier answer was not correct, I edited it now, you have to put $elemMatch in the fields object. Can you try it and see if it is working now?

Comment: Hmm that's strange.
This code `db.data.find({ 'Achievements.AchievementEventID': 0},{Buildings:0, Achievements: {$elemMatch: {AchievementEventID: 0}}})` works in web shell in documantations of mongodb, but on mongodb cloud in find field it doesn't work...

Comment: What is your mongo version in cloud?

Comment: Latest as I know – 4.0.12

Comment: But one problem with this solution - query return only one object (if number of objects with `AchievementEventID` more than 1, it's problem).

Answer (score 0):

- **You can use aggregate instead of a find like this**

  db.data.aggregate(
  `[{'$unwind':'$Achievements'},{$match:{
          'Achievements.AchievementEventID':0
          }},{$project:{
                      'AchievementID':'$Achievements.AchievementID',
              'AchievementEventID':'$Achievements.AchievementEventID'
              }}]`
  );